# Drop Down menu from hover to onclick

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, onclick

Hello everyone I know it's a question made over and over again but I just can't get it.... I'm starting a little now to understand CSS but java is a complete no no..... if someone can help me to put the `onclick` function to the following menu I would much apreciate it and hopefully I can start understanding a little how java works...here is how each HTML element for the menu bar starts:

```
<li><a href="#" class="drop">who we are</a><!-- Begin Home Item -->

    <div class="dropdown_chisiamo"><!-- Begin 2 columns container -->

        <div class="col_2">
            <h2>who we are</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="col_2">
```

Can someone please give me the JS script and briefly explain what goes where.

Thank you!

Comment: Java is not JavaScript, they are completely different, just unfortunately named.

Also, use something like jQuery or any other of the hundreds of pre made libraries that do this for you.